# Apache Changelog: 2.2.12 and 2.2.14

Tags: php, apache, process, version

I have huge PHP script which I have been running on Apache 2.2.12 and I have recently upgraded to Apache 2.2.14. However, my PHP script doesn't work as it stops at a certain point all the time. I have been trying to work out what the difference is in these two Apache versions, I have looked at this [CHANGELOG](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2.14) and have not been able to determine this.

When I look in my Apache error log, I find this before my PHP script fails to do anything else.

```
Parent: child process exited with status 255
```

The errors after this are just notices and they end after a few of these.

What changes in Apache do you think can cause this? I was reading around and I found a few people saying that newer versions of Apache on Vista (windows) can detect when a PHP script is in an infinite loop and will kill that child, is this true?

Thanks all for any input.

### Update

Apologies, this is no longer relevant. I think its a PHP issue. I switched from 5.2 to 5.3 and I think its do with modules. I will be openning another question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

download this

http://windows.php.net/downloads/snaps/php-5.2-win32-VC6-x86-latest.zip

then copy libmysql.dll into your php directory and restart apache

Comment: Is that something for MySQL? I do not use MySQL. I use SQLServer. Also, the same thing above has happened to me on my Windows 2003 server - the above is specific to Vista, right?

Comment: I think so, mysqk or any other, you may try yo update your dll files accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does not relate to modules, but to certain validations made by the core interpreter, which breaks many nonstrict processes in different PHP applications. *Beware of updating PHP to 5.3! Mwahahahaha!*

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: The thing is: PHP 5.3 itself includes several new validations, better explained here http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration53.changes.php

It means you have to test deeply before even trying to update any production environment, not just disable some modules in the mean time or something like that. Some CMS I tested got screwed heavily when taken to a testing environment with php5.3